# how to know if there's no new file in a folder with a hour

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm trying to make a program check if there's no file being created with a hour and will send an email,
Is there a way to know if there's no new file in a folder with in a example 5 hours
is filewatcher have that event?

Comment: To me, it is a bit unclear what you are asking? Can you describe the requirement a little more detailed? If you want to know if there isn't a file younger than x amount of time, you just need to find the youngest file and compare its created-timestamp to the desired offset. But I am unclear how you would want that in an event? What should that event be? When shall it be triggered?

Comment: This seems just a simple task for a Timer. FileSystemWatcher and events are not really involved here.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher doesn't have that specific event but it does have a Created event - so just get that event to restart a timer set for 5hrs & the timer event will send the email.

Comment: @PaulF That is if the application is in fact constantly running, maybe as a service. If this is the only task it has to do, I'd implement a one-time offset check and schedule it via the Task scheduler. But that's really very fishing in the dark. I think OP should be a little bit more verbose about the requirements and context.

Comment: @VonJustineNapalang Shall the email be sent **if there is** a file created in the timespan or **if not**?

Comment: @Fildor  its if not

Comment: this should run on background , this system will check if whith in an 1 hour if there's no new file in folder 1 it will send an email. am i doing it corect is console app will run on background?

Comment: What do you mean with "in background"? It will need a user to be logged on and a console (of course) which can be minimized, but it will be there. If you want it to run permanently ( and maybe as a service user, so no actual user needs to be logged on ) then the droid you are looking for is a Service. You can build a Service project in .net Framework and Core (a little bit more tricky, though), I don't know for Standard - haven't tried to do that before. There are plenty of how-to's and tutorials in written form, projects and video if you use the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that using the following steps

- Get All the files in the folder using [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)
- Iterate through all the files and get their creation date using [File.GetCreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_GetCreationTime_System_String_)
- Then compare the Creation time with the current time and check whether it's less than 1 hour or not.

  `var filePathList = Directory.GetFiles("rootPath");
  var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  var filesCreatedRecently = filesList.where(x => DateTime.Substract(currentDateTime, File.GetCreationTime(rooPath + x)).Hours < 1);`

Comment: "Where" is in System.Linq namespace and "DateTime.Substract" is in System namespace. Try including them. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8       
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.8